# Problem in understanding chain rule.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The chain rule for total derivative

---

Assume that $g : \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a \in \mathbb R^n$, with total derivative $Df(a)$ and let $b = g(a)$ and assume that $f : \mathbb R^m \longrightarrow \mathbb R^p$ is differentiable at $b \in \mathbb R^m$, with total derivative $Df(b)$. Then the composition function $h = f \circ g : \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^p$ is differentiable at $a \in \mathbb R^n$, and the total derivative $Dh(a)$ is given by

$Dh(a) = Df(b) \circ Dg(a)$, the composition of the linear functions $Df(b)$ and $Dg(a)$.

But I can't relate this concept to the chain rule involving partial derivatives as a linear combination.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $\;Dg(a)=a\;$  in your second line?

Comment: No @DonAntonio it's $b = g(a)$.

Comment: @A. Then that doesn't make much sense: in that first line, what is $\;f\;$ ? And then after that you say $\;f\;$ is differentiable at $\;b\;$ ...?

Comment: Are you speaking of the multi-variate chain rule that goes something like$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Comment: Yes @SimpleArt you are correct.Does there exist any similarity between these two?I fail to prove the equivalency between them if exists.Please help me.

Comment: Well, doesn't the following answer your question?:$$\frac d{dt}f(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: I want to prove the result for function $f$ of atleast two real variables $x$ and $y$ which are itself a function of a real variable $t$ with the help of the composite chain rule which I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y$ be differentiable functions of $t$ and $f$ a differentiable function of $x,y$.  Then, by the definition of a total derivative,

$$\begin{align}\frac d{dt}f(x(t),y(y))&=\vphantom{\cfrac11}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x(t+h),y(t+h))-f(x(t),y(t))}h\\&=\vphantom{\cfrac11}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\color{#44bb88}{f(x(t+h),y(t+h))-f(x(t),y(t+h))}+\color{#4488dd}{f(x(t),y(t+h)-f(x(t),y(t))}}h\\&=\vphantom{\cfrac11}\lim_{h\to0}\color{#44bb88}{\frac{f(x(t+h),y(t+h))-f(x(t),y(t+h))}h}+\color{#4488dd}{\frac{f(x(t),y(t+h)-f(x(t),y(t))}h}\\&=\vphantom{\cfrac11}\lim_{h\to0}\color{#44bb88}{\frac{f(x(t+h),y(t+h))-f(x(t),y(t+h))}{x(t+h)-x(t)}\frac{x(t+h)-x(t)}h}\\&+\vphantom{\cfrac11}\lim_{h\to0}\color{#4488dd}{\frac{f(x(t),y(t+h)-f(x(t),y(t))}{y(t+h)-y(t)}\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}h}\\&=\vphantom{\cfrac11}\color{#44bb88}{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}}+\color{#4488dd}{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}}\end{align}$$

In general, we end up with

$\frac d{dt}f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_k)=\sum_{p=1}^k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_p}\frac{dx_p}{dt}$

And if we do this for one variable, we end up with

$\frac d{dt}f(x(t))=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}=f'(x(t))x'(t)$

which is normal chain rule.

Comment: But in the chapter multivariable calculus of T.M. Apostol's Mathematical Analysis I have studied the concept of chain rule which I already gave in my post.But I find difficulty to compare these two chain rules.One is "Chain rule for finding total derivative (or linear operator) of composite function" and the other as you already mentioned "multivariable chain rule".How is these two concepts related?I am saying this question since both of them are "chain rules".Please help me to understand this concept.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay I added in the last few lines.  It shows that when reducing multi-variate chain rule down to one 'variable', we end up with the other chain rule.

Comment: Look my latest edit @Simple Art.The function mentioned in my post is multivariable not of one variable and the total derivative mentioned here is a linear operator not a real number.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay I do not understand the question if my last edit did not clarify.  Sorry :-(

Comment: Sorry @Simple Art.I think now my post is not misunderstood.Is it clear now?

Comment: @SimpleArt what is the use of `\vphantom{\cfrac11}` $\vphantom{\cfrac11}$?

Comment: @A---B Basically, `\phantom{}` and `\vphantom{}` create invisible horizontal and vertical spacing based on what's inside the `{}`.  Here, I just used a fraction, so it changed the vertical height of each line to fit the invisible fraction.  If you remove it, the lines become more squashed together and it becomes harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : \mathbb R^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function of two real variables $x$ and $y$ which are functions of a real variable $t$.

Let us now first construct a function $g : \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$ defined as $g(t) = (x(t),y(t))$, $t \in \mathbb R$. Let $g$ be differentiable at $a \in \mathbb R$ and $f$ be differentiable at $g(a) = (x(a),y(a))$. Now it is not hard to see that $f \circ g (t) = f(x,y)$. Then according to your post $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and therefore

$$D(g \circ f)(a) = Df(g(a)) \circ Dg(a)$$

It implies that $$D(g \circ f)(a)(1) = Df(g(a))(Dg(a)(1))$$$$ = Df(g(a))(g'(a)) = Df(g(a))(x'(a),y'(a)) = Ax'(a) + By'(a)$$ where $A = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} {\vert}_{(x(a),y(a))}$ and $B = \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} {\vert}_{(x(a),y(a))}$. So we ultimately have

---

$\frac {d}{dt}(f \circ g) {\vert}_{t=a} = \frac {d}{dt} f(x,y) {\vert}_{(x(a),y(a))} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} {\vert}_{(x(a),y(a))}.\frac {dx}{dt} {\vert}_{t=a} + \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} {\vert}_{(x(a),y(a))}.\frac {dy}{dt} {\vert}_{t=a}$.

Which is the required multivariable chain rule for a function of two real variables as you mentioned in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to see with linear (well, affine) functions.

If $f(x) = Fx +a, g(x) = Gx+b$ then $h(x)=f(g(x)) = FGx + Fb +a$.

Since $Df(x) = F, Dg(x) = G$ and $Dh(x) = FG$, we see that
$Dh(x) = Df(g(x)) DG(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling "this concept" **is** the chain rule, and the formula $$h'(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n {\partial f\over\partial x_k}\bigl({\bf x}(t)\bigr)\>x_k'(t)$$
for a function $$h:=f\circ{\bf x}:\quad {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R},\qquad t\mapsto h(t):=f\bigl({\bf x}(t)\bigr)$$ is a special case of this concept.