# Definition of Total Derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $x(t), y(t) :  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  be suitably differentiable functions.

Looking up *Total Derivative* of $f(x(t), y(t)$ most references I can find, e.g.
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Total_Derivative
https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/45533
**define** it as
$\frac d{dt}f(x(t),y(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} $

One answer on stack exchange https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075304 defines it as I would expect
$\frac d{dt}f(x(t),y(t)) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x(t+h),y(t+h))-f(x(t),y(t))}h$
and then derives the above result as a consequence

**So, what is the definition ?**

Comment: In my mind, I don't even use the term "total derivative". If $g(t) = f(x(t), y(t))$, then we can take the *derivative* of $g$, and of course $\frac{dg}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$. There is no separate concept of a ``total derivative"; we are merely taking the derivative of the function $g$.

Comment: The first equation is most certainly not a definition of any sort; it is a theorem (a simple consequence of the chain rule as explained by the very nice answer below). The second is indeed the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a scalar field, for example the pressure assigned to each point of the Euclidean space.

Let  $\gamma\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ be a curve – think about $\gamma(t)$ as the position of an airplane at a given time $t$.

We can compose these functions to get
$$f\circ \gamma\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R,$$
which assigns to a given moment $t$, the pressure $f(\gamma(t))$ measured around the airplane.

Then the "total derivative" at $t$ is nothing else as the ordinary derivative $(f\circ \gamma)'(t)$. The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case) says that
$$(f\circ \gamma)'(t) = f'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t),$$
which is sometimes spelled as
$$\frac{df}{dt} = \sum_k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} \frac{dx^k}{dt},$$
although I personally find this notation more confusing than the first one.